# Show loading icon/gif until results returned from api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, loading

I am making a call to an api and the results take about 15-20 seconds to load, so I would like to show a loading gif for example until they load.

i have a simple form that makes the request which then redirects me to the relevant action

```
<%= form_tag results_path, :method => "get" do %>
<%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder => "Enter Email Address here...." %>
<%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
```

How would I add an image to the results_path until results are rendered?

Can i do this within the form itself or is it a piece of Jquery/Javascript

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

According to [Rails 3: Remote links and Forms](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/), you could do it as such

- Add `:remote => true` to your `form_tag`
- Add the following to your JS

```js
$('SEARCH-BUTTON').bind('ajax:loading', function(){
  $('LOADING-GIF').show();
});

$('SEARCH-BUTTON').bind('ajax:complete', function(){
  $('LOADING-GIF').hide();
  // add what you like here
});
```

I have not tested it, but I think it would do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the link and answer, so in my scenario at present the results are shown on the results page and for example is just <%= @results %>, this needs to be moved to the index view (the place where the search form is) is that right as the request and response will happen on the same page

Comment: @Richlewis Right. Or, just to keep things organized and as is, modify `results_path` so it would respond to `json` by using `respond_to`. Googling 'respond_to json` will list thousands of examples.

Answer (score 1):

This would disable the button with spinner until the response is received.

```
<%= button_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-default", 'data-disable-with' => "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>".html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by calling the api  asynchronously. i dont know how to do that in ruby but this is the general idea.  The api will be called in background and till then you loading icon will be displayed. when the api is fully fetched then you can remove the loading icon.